# How is the perturbation in one column of a symmetric matrix reflected in its eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a 0-1 square symmetric matrix. Then it's eigenvalues are real. But I have observed that by multiplying any of its column by a positive constant, even if the matrix is not symmetric still its eigenvalues are real. Further, the inertia (the number of positive, negative, zero eigenvalues) remains the same. Now how to prove these observations. 
Also if possible, suggest me - 'what is the relationship between the spectra of the two matrices?'.

Comment: Your title calls this a "perturbation" so are we safe to assume the positive constant is close to $1$? Or is this for any positive constant?

Comment: It is applicable for any positive constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, suppose $A$ is a real symmetric matrix and $D$ is a positive diagonal matrix. By Sylvester's law of inertia, the inertia of $A$ and $B=D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}$ are identical to each other. Yet, $B$ is similar to $AD$ because $B=D^{1/2}(AD)D^{-1/2}$. Hence $AD$ has identical spectrum to $B$ and in turn it has the same inertia as $A$.

In your case, $D$ is obtained from modifying exactly one entry of the identical matrix to an arbitrary positive value. So, the above argument applies too.

There are some known bounds on the eigenvalues of $AD$ based on the eigenvalues of $A$. E.g. when the eigenvalues are arranged in descending order, it is known that the sum of squared differences between the two ordered spectra are bounded by the squared Frobenius norm of $D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}-A$ (cf. Stewart and Sun, *Matrix Perturbation Theory*, Academic Press). For bounds like this, you may consult any book or research paper on matrix perturbation theory.